# How to change internal Django representation of date?

Tags: django, sqlite

2018-08-26
I need this and hours, minutes, seconds.

Using sqlite3 and python3.6.

---

```
dic.update({thread: OnePost.objects.filter(published_date = thread.published_date)})
```

The result is {only_one_thread: and_all_post_published_in_day_when_thread_was_published}.

```
published_date = models.DateField() #in both models Thread and ONePost
```

Origin of problem is that only days are distinguishable. Need seconds.

Comment: Please tag your database, add details about your data model (table struct + django model), how and where you are trying to get your date format but failing (I guess this is in a `view` so `view` and `template` code would be helpful too).

Comment: Both `timezone.now()` and `datetime.now()` return a datetime which includes hours, minutes, and seconds.

Comment: @IvanStarostin thx for response. https://github.com/RomanMIzulin/trindec  https://github.com/RomanMIzulin/trindec/blob/master/board/threads/views.py line 16. An idea is unique time of thread and first post of thread( and id of thread and thread_id of OnePost, but this is off topic).

Comment: @Roman update your question with all the details needed.

Comment: @IvanStarostin done

Comment: `models.DateField() -> models.DateTimeField()` ?

Comment: @IvanStarostin meine respektierung

Answer (score 0, accepted):

models.DateField() -> models.DateTimeField()